# iOS : Xcode Crash when configure SVN

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, xcode4, xcode4.2

At the time i Was checkout and clone project with local file path in my XCODE is crash.

When i enter file path "file:///iOS/svnProject" in location field xcode is crash please help for the same please see the attached image.[image]

My Xcode Version is 4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an external client, such as [svnx](https://code.google.com/p/svnx/). XCode isn't the strongest in handling repositories and working copies properly anyway.